# How to create a version-independent, standalone function from a trained scikit-learn model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deployment

I have a question about deploying `scikit-learn` models.  I understand `pickle` and `joblib`, and they work.  But I would like the use of the trained model to be as independent as possible, ideally completely independent, of python versions, scikit versions, etc.

In other words, once I have developed and trained a classification model, all I want is a function that I can distribute that takes the input variables in some format (array, data frame, whatever) and returns the score, eg, in the case of `AdaBoostClassifier` the output of `model.decision_function(data)`.

I do not care about storing the training/test datasets, I do not care about "rebuilding" the model.  All I want is a standalone function, I guess with the parameters of the trained models hardcoded for whatever version of scikit I had used originally. Is that even possible?

I read about PMML which is based on pipelines (right?). I do not use pipelines because I do not want/need to curate/transform the data. Actually, I do a little bit, but I much prefer to do it by hand so that I *really* know what I am doing (!). I also do not really understand the pipelines documentation, sigh.  Anyway, if I were to save the model into a PMML file, would that then achieve independence from software versions?  (I am currently using Python 3.11.5 scikit-learn 1.3.0)

Thanks

PS: if using PMML is the answer, can somebody please point me in the right direction on how to modify my code, which at the moment looks (sort of) like this

```
base_classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1, min_samples_leaf=0.015)

model = AdaBoostClassifier(base_classifier, 
algorithm="SAMME.R", learning_rate=0.15, n_estimators=40)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

where `X_train` is a `pandas.DataFrame` with all the variables, and `y_train` is the "yes/no" flag.